# Highlight subsections below current section, while shade other (sub)sections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, highlighting

I want my slides to show like this, that the current section and its subsections highlighted, while other section and subsections shown but shaded:
[image: Good look]
http://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/beamer-tutorial.pdf

But I followed its instruction and also tried other ways suggested by related questions, I failed to do that. For example, if I use the following code, I get only the title of the section highlighted but not the subsections:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

By a video on Youtube (I cannot add the link due to the reputation restriction), this code seems work. I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I am afraid, you will have to post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), because your code snipped produces exactly the image you showed when combined with a beamer document with default setting.

Comment: I edited my question to give an MWE.

Comment: mmmm, strange! With your code I get http://i.stack.imgur.com/mbYo7.png, which I think is exactly what you want. What version are you using? I am on texlive 2015 with beamer version 2015/01/05 3.36

Comment: Thanks for help. Yes, that is what I want, but it just does work for me. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXstudio 2.9.4.

Comment: Beamer version is quite old: beamer.cls,v 70f9d8411e54 2011/09/12.

Comment: Can you try to update beamer?

Comment: Yes. I updated some packages and it works now, although I failed to compile it with something like "amsmath is not found" before I updated the packages for the second time. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because update solved the problem